# Django: Foreign Key Error when extending the default USER scheme

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I am currently struggling with the extension of the User model with the relation `OneToOneField`.

I have the following model:

```python
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    qualified_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=17, blank=True)
    buyout = models.BooleanField(default=False)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

The following forms:

```python
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator, ValidationError
from .models import Profile


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control inp-xlf', 'id': 'email', 'placeholder': 'name@example.com'}),
        required=True)

    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=False)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=False)

    def clean(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data

        email_cleaned = cd.get('email')
        virtual_passwd = User.objects.make_random_password()
        cd.setdefault("password1", virtual_passwd)
        cd.setdefault("password2", virtual_passwd)
        cd.setdefault('username', email_cleaned.split("@")[0])
        return cd

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)


class ProfileRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    qualified_name = forms.CharField(strip=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control inp-xlf', 'id': 'name', 'placeholder': 'Enter your name...'}))

    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                                 message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits "
                                         "allowed.")
    phone_number = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control inp-xlf', 'id': 'phone',
                                                                 'placeholder': '(+41) 254 48 95'}),
                                   validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17)  # validators should be a list

    buyout_checkbox = forms.BooleanField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={"class": "form-check-input", "id": "buyout"}), required=False)

    gdpr_checkbox = forms.BooleanField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={"class": "form-check-input", "id": "gdpr"}),
        required=True)

    def clean(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data

        gdpr_check = cd.get('gdpr_checkbox')

        if not gdpr_check:
            raise ValidationError("Mandatory fields were not provided")

        return cd

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('qualified_name', 'phone_number', 'buyout_checkbox', 'gdpr_checkbox')
```

The following view:

```python
from django.db import transaction
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, ProfileRegisterForm
from django.contrib import messages


@transaction.atomic
def leads_page(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileRegisterForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()

            username = user_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            gdpr_checkbox = profile_form.cleaned_data.get('gdpr_checkbox')
            
            messages.success(request, f"Account created for user: {username}.")
            return redirect('leads-main-page')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Validation failed")
    else:
        user_form = UserRegisterForm()
        profile_form = ProfileRegisterForm()

    return render(request, 'leads/leads-page.html', context={'user_form': user_form,'profile_form': profile_form})
```

Having all of the above set and performing: makemigrations -> migrate -> runserver, then on the form post the user is not created at all and this afterwards causes the following error:

```
base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
[12/Dec/2021 11:58:00] "POST /trucksclaims/ HTTP/1.1" 500 95351
```

where the stack trace does not show, the causing function from my actual source code, however, I do expect that this is caused because the `user_form.save()` does not create any user instance. This can be observed in the attached view by checking the return value of the `user_form.save()`.

#### Question

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I cannot find the root cause to proceed immediate fixture.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why are you creating a Profile model when you can just extends the user model provided by Django ?

Comment: i don't think your create direct relation like that you have to first subclass `User` then u can given one to on relation with any table

Comment: Firstly, according to the Django documentation, this is the valid way f the extension: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model